# Wordpress not loading Woocommerce attributes section in product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

While I tried to add a new product to My Wordpress Woocommerce site. The **Product data -> attributes** section shows a loading icon and not allowing to add new Attributes to the page. [image]

Because of this issue I updated the Wordpress and Woocommerce to new version. Also I tried to deactivate some plugin. Nothing works. I installed the following plugins in My Wordpress site.

1. Booster for WooCommerce
2. Contact Form 7
3. Envato WordPress Toolkit
4. Google Analytics Counter Tracker
5. Header and Footer Scripts
6. Jetpack by WordPress.com
7. Nancy Shortcodes
8. WPBakery Visual Composer

My Google chrome console showing the following error.
[image]

Comment: Looks like it is hanging due to a JS error. Can you open the page up in chrome and then bring up the console in dev tools to view the output and add it to your question?

Comment: I added My console window. It showing an error like you said. How to solve the issue?

Comment: Are you using visual composer? try by disabling that

Comment: The problem solved but most of My WordPress site themes are running using Visual Composer.

Comment: Are you using a pre-bought theme or have you built the site yourself? If it is pre-bought what is the name of it?

Comment: I bough it from Themeforest and its name is Nancy.

Comment: Check to see if there is a theme update which includes and update for the plugin. It looks to be a known issue with the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem happening because of the `Visual Composer` Plugin.

**Solution for The Problem:**
The problem can be solved by UN-installing the Visual Composer Plugin and install the latest version of the plugin.

The direct plugin update will not work sometimes, So try to install by removing the folder of the plugin from the WordPress and upload the latest version manually and do the update.

Try to update the plugin with the Ultimate Visual Composer Version `3.16.12`. This will solve your problem.